# Imagem responsiva com background cover

Tags: css

Estou tentando deixa essa imagem responsiva com background cover, porém a imagem não está aparecendo, fiz o teste no h1 pra ver se era o css, mais não sei onde o erro.

```css
#imagem {
         background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Y7V4zrd.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        
h1{
    color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
    <div id="imagem"></div>
    <h1>TEXTO</h1>
```

Sei que a propriedade cover é a forma mais eficaz de deixa a imagem responsiva por isto estou tentando usar ela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#imagem {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Y7V4zrd.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
        
h1{
    color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
  <div id="imagem">
    <h1>TEXTO</h1>
    <h1>TEXTO 2</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado vlw, so não entendi onde eu errei, tentei mais não achei.

Comment: Você abriu a div e fechou logo após, não colocando nada dentro dela, logo o seu background não ficou visível, pois sua div não continha nada. O que eu fiz foi apenas colocar o fechamento da sua div após a tag h1.

Comment: vlw aceitei a resposta